# Kernel died, restarting in the middle of my simulation (spyder)

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am using the spyder interface with a python script that works through many time steps in succession. At a random point in my code, the process will terminate and the console will say "kernel died, restarting...". I tried running the same script in pycharm and the process also terminates, seemingly at a random point, with some exit code which I assume means the same thing.

Anyone have any tips on how to get rid of this problem? Even a workaround so I can get some work done. This is incredibly frustrating.

Note: I recently moved and got a new router and internet service, not sure if that might affect things.

Comment: Check memory usage, maybe it's killed by OS..

Comment: But why would this happen all of the sudden when I've had no problems with the same script in the past? It's just really random. I'm not exactly sure how to check memory but when running, task manager says 30% of my memory is being utilized, 5% of "disk" and 20% cpu...

Comment: Update. Older versions of the script are working fine. I must have done something iPython didn't like. I am going back to the older version and redoing the updates to find out exactly what is wrong. Thanks.